# AWS Cognito user pool OAuth REST API call examples exist?

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

It feels like amazon are encouraging people to just use their client SDK, but it would be nice to see what a sequence of valid REST calls looks like for the authorization and implicit grant flows.

The AWS documentation for the authorization and token endpoints is a nice start:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html

Does anybody know if some examples exist showing the sequence of REST calls for the Implicit and Authorization flows (against Cognito)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is a bit shoddy, but here's an example PHP cURL call to get the ID/Access Tokens using your authorization code for the Authorization flow:-

```html
$url = 'https://<YOURDOMAIN>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token';
$client_key = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
$client_secret = '<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>';

$data = [       'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id'=>$client_key, 'code'=>$_GET["code"],
                'redirect_uri'=>'<YOUR_REDIRECT_URI>'];

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client_key . ":" . $client_secret);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$field_string = http_build_query($data);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $field_string);
$resp = json_decode(curl_exec($handle),true);
```

Once you've got the ID token you need to parse the JWK JSON file from

```
https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<USER_POOL_ID/.well-known/jwks.json
```

and then lookup the kid field in the token header, and use that as the secret to decode the token.  I used this library:-
https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

So the token validation code looks something like:-

```html
$jwks_json = file_get_contents("https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<USER_POOL_ID>/.well-known/jwks.json");
$jwk = JWK::parseKeySet($jwks_json);

$tks = explode('.', <YOUR_TOKEN>);
list($headb64, $bodyb64, $cryptob64) = $tks;
$jwt_header = json_decode(base64_decode($headb64),true);
$jwt_body = json_decode(base64_decode($bodyb64),true);
$key=$jwk[$jwt_header["kid"]];

try
{
    $decoded = JWT::decode(<YOUR_TOKEN>, $key, array($jwt_header["alg"]));
    $decoded_array = (array) $decoded;
    // GREAT SUCCESS!
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    // TOKEN COULDN'T BE VALIDATED
}
```

Comment: After I get the access token or kid, how can I use these to make user UpdatrAttribute rest call? What information need to pass in post authentication requests to perform various operations on User data?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything with it nicely documented. I think your best option would be to spin up a test app using one of the SDKs and monitor the network traffic. It seems the API is not well documented.